# How to give checkbox gradient in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Is there a way to implement a checkbox with a gradient in flutter? I tried using the Checkbox class but was not able to implement a linear gradient? How shall I go about it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it with a container and change the height and width like this:

```
Container(height: 19,
              width: 19,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topLeft, 
                    end: Alignment(10, 3), 
                    colors: <Color>[
                      Colors.white, 
                      Colors.grey,
              ],
            )
            ),
              child: Checkbox(value: false,),
            ),
```